# When using ADB with an usb cable on Android, what are the permissions when running a shell?

Tags: android, permissions, adb

Is the shell run as root ?
Can you sudo on a non-rooted phone ?

Answer (score 1):

> Is the shell run as root ?

On Android Emulators, if you run

```
$ adb shell
```

You will enter the phone as `root`, e.g. you will see something like

```
root@generic_x86:/ #
```

But, on the real non-rooted devices, you can still run `adb shell`, but you will only have a normal user permission.

> Can you sudo on a non-rooted phone ?

Cannot.